# Is something better than wine?

Tags: wine, emulation

Are there any better "emulators" (wine is not emulator) than wine?

Answer (score 3):

There are the [CrossOver](http://www.codeweavers.com/products/) products from CodeWeavers, which are basically more polished commercial versions of Wine. Or you can run a VM like [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) and buy a licensed copy of Windows to run in it.